# session reset when php script is called by tier

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, session-variables

i've a problem with a php script. The script is called by a tier server. My script called is on the subdomain *scripts.mydomain.com* and it call another script on the subdomain *beta.mydomain.com*

i have set my configuration to share session between all subdomain of my domain.

If i try manually, session values are well shared when i call scripts.mydomain.com that call beta.mydomain.com

But when it's the external server who call scripts.mydomain.com, session values are not saved. I check the session id and i discover the id was different on scripts.mydomain.com and beta.domain.com when the external server call. When it's me, id are same.

i use a `header("Location: http://beta.mydomain.com");` in *scripts.mydomain.com*

*(PS : i can't use GET to give parameters, it's the constraint)*

after, i think use a jquery AJAX fonction to call my scripts.mydomain.com

Same issue, the javascript fonction is not called, but when i call the script, the javascript is well used and script.mydomain.com was successfully called by my ajax function.

Somebody help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session values are stored within each instance's PHP session temporary folder. Your case sounds like you're using two separate server or two instances of PHP. Hence if you use two instances of PHP (one on beta and another on scripts), your session values are stored separately i.e. scripts stored on scripts, beta stored on beta. Although your session identifier may be shared between the two instances through cookies, the second instance can't find the values from the first instance.

What I suggest is that you:

1. put both instances' session temporary folder to point to a common folder (if on same server)
2. use a session database driver and separate database server that serves storage of session information

Comment: Ok but if i store session values in my database with scripts.mydomaine.com , and if i consult my database width beta.mydomain.com, how i know what information to retrieve ? the session_id is different on each when it's the external server that call the script. And all sessions of subdomains are saved in the both folder yet.